# receive rtsp stream with vlc

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, rtp

I need to transmit video with gstreamer via rtp protocol.
this is the server code who transmit 'testing':

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>


static gboolean
timeout (GstRTSPServer * server, gboolean ignored)
{
  GstRTSPSessionPool *pool;

  pool = gst_rtsp_server_get_session_pool (server);
  gst_rtsp_session_pool_cleanup (pool);
  g_object_unref (pool);

  return TRUE;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMediaMapping *mapping;
  GstRTSPMediaFactoryURI *factory;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  if (argc < 2) {
    g_message ("usage: %s <uri>", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* create a server instance */
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

  /* get the mapping for this server, every server has a default mapper object
  * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
  mapping = gst_rtsp_server_get_media_mapping (server);

  /* make a URI media factory for a test stream. */
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_uri_new ();
   /* when using GStreamer as a client, one can use the gst payloader, which is
   * more efficient when there is no payloader for the compressed format */
  /* g_object_set (factory, "use-gstpay", TRUE, NULL); */
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_uri_set_uri (factory, argv[1]);
  /* if you want multiple clients to see the same video, set the shared property
   * to TRUE */
  /* gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared ( GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY (factory), TRUE); */

  /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
  gst_rtsp_media_mapping_add_factory (mapping, "/test",
      GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY (factory));

  /* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */
  g_object_unref (mapping);

  /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
  if (gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL) == 0)
    goto failed;

  g_timeout_add_seconds (2, (GSourceFunc) timeout, server);

  /* start serving */
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  return 0;

  /* ERRORS */
failed:
  {
    g_print ("failed to attach the server\n");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

on another computer, I run vlc and when i try to connect to the server, i get error: VLC could not connect to '192.168.1.22:8554'

if someone know what im doing wrong, it will be great.

thanks!

Comment: what url are you using for vlc?

Comment: from the client: rtsp://192.168.1.22:8554/test.

if I try to receive in loopback:  rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test.

and the error with loopback is: <pre>  VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test'. Check the log for details.<code>

and in the shell (with loopback):
<pre> GLib (gthread-posix.c): Unexpected error from C library during 'pthread_mutex_lock': Invalid argument.  Aborting.
Aborted (core dumped)<code>

Comment: can ffmpeg receive from that url? wonder if it's related to this... https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=116701 what about earlier versions of vlc?